# Execute multiple commands after [ test

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

How can I use a simple one-line test and execute multiple commands if the test is true?
The following does not work:

```
for f in $source_dir/*.mov
do
   [ ! -f "$f" ] && echo "No files in source directory. Exiting."; break || continue
   # a bunch of commands
done
```

I got it to work using the below code, but I feel like there should be as simpler way.

```
for f in $source_dir/*.mov
do
   if [ ! -f "$f" ]; then
      echo "No files in source directory.  Exiting."
      break
   else
      # a bunch of commands
   fi
done
```

Comment: ... That's what `if` and `[` were designed for, why do you think there "should be a simpler way"?

Comment: FWIW, you can chain `&&`: `[ ! -f "$f" ] && echo ... && break`. But if you throw in `||`, beware that, unlike c-like languages, it is the same precedence as `&&` -- `a || b && c` is equivalent to `{a || b} && c`, NOT `a || {b && c}` as you might expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `{`:

```
[[ ! -f "$f" ]] && { this; that; break; } || { the_other; ...; }
```

Whether that's "simpler" or not is a question of aesthetics.

Using `[[` instead of `[` is optional. But it's usually better.